# file processing(input from a file)

Tags: c++, file-processing

i have a simple text file with columns first name, last name and nickname...i was trying to get the inputs from each row in the file in a c++ program....then a problem cropped up...i had left out filling columns of a few rows....here is a sample table:

```
avinash kumar snu
akash         aks
        rohan ron
```

now i am inputting the columns into first, last and nick field of objects of people class using c++....
now when i input for 2nd row aks goes in the 'last' field and for 3rd row rohan goes in the 'first' field and ron goes in the 'last' field....so can anyone suggest a way by which i can fix this up......if it cant be fixed can i  at least know how many columns have actually been input(means number of columns) ?

Comment: Are the columns all of a fixed size? If so then the solution is trivial, if not then you have a real problem on your hands.

Comment: @mark..no the colums have a max size....but no fixed size

Comment: Are your columns in the file separated by whitespace?

Comment: fgets-trim-tokenize-save; for two or less tokens on a line artificial intelligence should do the magic.

Comment: @brian...yes they are separated by white space

Comment: Simple then. If there's more than one space between columns, you know that column is missing. You're going to have to parse the lines.

Comment: @brian...in fact all columns are left aligned too

Comment: @brian....i thought of that..but what about 'arvi  kashh   arvn'(these  are separated by more than one spaces)

Comment: You enjoy making parsing difficult don't you. Why not inserts some commas in between each of the names. Then at least each name will be delimited by comma. If you are generating the data from a DB or spreadsheet then this should be easy as they will both support generating the data automatically in "CSV" format.

Comment: @mark...can i have something like two delimiting characters while using getline because i dont know whether after a particular input '\n' follows(if only one column is there) or ' ' follows(if two or more)...so is there any function which allows like the delimiting character can be ' ' or '\n'..(i am following the solution given by brian)

Answer (score 1):

As Brian and Andrejs have commented, you'll have to parse the file line by line. Assuming there's always at least one name and never more than three, then you have 7 possibilites (0 where there's no name):

A B C,

A B 0,
A 0 C,
0 B C,

A 0 0,
0 B 0,
0 0 C

Parse the line and save the names in a temporary variable. Also save the starting position of each name within the line. In case you get less than 3 names, you can logically determine which name(s) are missing, based on max length of a line. Hope this makes sense, it's not very elegant solution :)

Comment: Reading your question again: are you sure that the names don't start on fixed positions? It would be much easier if you can assume that.

Comment: @jork....can i have something like two delimiting characters while using getline because i dont know whether after a particular input '\n' follows(if only one column is there) or ' ' follows(if two or more)...so is there any function which allows like the delimiting character can be ' ' or '\n'...

Comment: You can choose a delimiting character with getline() ([link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/)), but not more than one. I don't think it really matters, becasue you'll be reading line by line (there'll always be a '\n' delimiter) into a string, after that you'll be making substrings. Maybe you should look up string tokenizing.

Comment: substrings by using strtok()?

Comment: @avinash You tagged your question c++, so if you want to do it c++ way, use `string` and it's member functions, like substr().

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3595/discussion-between-avinash-and-jrok)